# How can I turnoff case sensitive matching from Vertica ? Either Globally or session wise

Tags: unicode, case-sensitive, vertica

Can I turn case-sensitive data handling from Vertica off session wise . I want it to be dependent on user who may either want to keep it case-sensitive or otherwise !

Also Is there any key to be modified while logging in to mark the session on for Unicode data handling ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed ways. I did not test them fully, so there might be corner cases I am not aware of. The keyword you are looking for is [collation](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/COLLATION.htm). You specifically want to update the [colstrength keyword](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Locales/LongForm.htm%3FTocPath%3DAdministrator's%20Guide%7CAbout%20Locales%7CLocale%20Specification%7C_____1) and you want a value of 1 I believe (case and accents are ignored).

You can do it in a few ways:

- vsql-only : `\locale en_US@colstrength=1`
- from anywhere including via ODBC/JDBC statements: `SET LOCALE TO 'en_US@colstrength=1';`
- by overriding the Locale value in your DSN (not tested) usually in /etc/odbc.ini for odbc

To show the effect, here is an example, first with the default, then after changing the locale:

```
\locale
en_US@collation=binary

select 'me' = 'ME';
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)

SET LOCALE TO 'en_US@colstrength=1';

\locale
en_US@colstrength=1

select 'me' = 'ME';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

I am pretty sure there is more to it, but this should get you started.